# C++ reinterpret_cast core in Linux, but run succsee in MAC

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

In some case,I want malloc a block memory, example: first part of memory will contains strings, second part memory will contains long type data. so, i try the demo code below.

the code below can run success in MAC, but core dump in Linux.

valgrind res:

[valgrind result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPchJ.png)

where:

1. line 7 is: `str[0] = key.data();`
2. line 13 is `test_cache(cache, "test");`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

void test_cache(char *cache, std::string key) {
  std::string* str = reinterpret_cast<std::string*> (cache);
  str[0] = key.data();
}

int main()
{
  char *cache = reinterpret_cast<char *> (calloc(1000, 1));
  test_cache(cache, "test");
  std::string* str = reinterpret_cast<std::string*> (cache);
  printf("%s\n",str[0].c_str());
  free(cache);
}
```

Comment: By using a string pointer without constructing a string object, you have undefined behavior.  Undefined means anything can happen, including appearing to work normally.  But you can never count on it.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object before its lifetime has started. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior; crash is another. `cache` doesn't contain an instance of `std::string`. You can't just pretend it's there, you have to construct it there.

Comment: i get the point, thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). You are right in using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/), but of course you should read its documentation (and also consider using [address sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), and be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

### My recommendation is to enable all warnings and debug information when compiling your C++ code.

With GCC, that means using `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile your C++ code.

In C++, the favorite way to use dynamic memory allocation is not to use the `malloc` and `free` functions from C, but to use [`::operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). There are cases where you could redefine your `new`. Be however aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html) as an excellent coding rule.

In practice, on several C++ implementations, `new` might call `malloc` before calling the constructor and `delete` might call `free` after calling the destructor. When `malloc` fails, `new` should throw an exception.

See also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report for more detailed explanations, focused on recent GCC (e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in summer 2020).

In C++, you want to take advantage of the powerful standard C++ library, so use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings, and learn to use [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

> ```
> std::string* str = reinterpret_cast<std::string*> (cache);
> ```

**cannot work** (since a standard string knows its size in addition of the bytes memory zone). You may want

```
 auto str = new std::string(cache);
```

or

```
 std::string str(cache);
```

Be scared of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and read later the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (or a later one).

Consider using, on your entire C++ program, static source code analyzers like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)++ or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). If you are allowed to use [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/), consider using [its static analysis facilities](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html), or writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) for static analysis purposes. If, in summer 2020, your GCC is older than GCC 10, do [compile GCC 10 from its source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) (after getting permission from your manager or client). Of course, writing a GCC plugin may take months of work, so is worthwhile for large C++ programs.

BTW, both [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) C++ compilers, so you are allowed to download then study their source code. In particular, do glance inside the implementation details of `std::string`

Comment: thanks for your professional answer and suggestions, i'll keep learning, thanks very much